# Portal account owner must have a role

Tags: apex, batch, error

I am trying to insert portal users in using dev console but it is showing this ERROR MESSAGE

> Line: 34, Column: 1  System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account
>   owner must have a role: []

NOTE I am the account owner and I have a role and contact is inserted and users are not

CODE

```
 List<User> usersToBeInserted = new List<User>();
 List<Contact> contactsToBeInserted = new List<Contact>();
 Account a = new Account(Id='001V000000OxY7M');
 for(integer i=0;i<20;++i)
 {
 Contact c=new Contact();
 c.Account=a;
 String ln='ContactLastNa'+i;
 c.LastName=ln;
 //c.LastName='ContactLastName'+[i];
 contactsToBeInserted.add(c);

 }
 insert contactsToBeInserted;

 for (integer i=0;i<20;++i)
 {
 User u=new user();
 String str=i+'batchuser@gmail.com';
 String mail =i+'batchuseremail@gmail.com';
 u.ProfileId= '00e70000001K1Zh';
 u.LastName ='Lastname'+i;
 u.Alias='BtchUsr'+i;
 u.Email=mail;
 u.Username=str;
 u.CommunityNickname='Batchuser'+i;
 u.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
 u.ContactId =contactsToBeInserted[i].Id;
 u.TimeZoneSidKey='GMT';
 u.languagelocalekey='en_US';
 u.localesidkey='en_US';
 usersToBeInserted.add(u);
 }
 insert usersToBeInserted;
```

Comment: Never hard code your ids!

Comment: I am planning to run this as execute anonymous for testing my code it's not actual code I am giving to client

Comment: We are but a sum of our habits. And that is one you should drill out of yourself as vigorously as possible. It also makes it pretty difficult for us to assess the data you are acting on.

Comment: Don't worry I avoid the use of hard coded values in finished products otherwise tech lead will not leave a chance to educate me and suggest me best practices.